# Large WAL files

Tags: prometheus

We are using Prometheus 2.2.1 and we are scraping just relatively few metrics (~30k once per minute).
We noticed that our disk consumption is quite high (much higher than 1.3B advertised by documentation). 2 hour chunk has 19MB (should be around 4.6MB=1.3*30k*2*60).

And the worse part are WAL files, each having ~256MB (server is running for 1 day). So we were expecting consumption of disk around 12*5MB=60MB (+ relatively small WAL), but the real usage is 566MB.

Is this expected behaviour? Will the WAL logs clean up after some time? Or is the approx consumption per sample 13B expected (10 times higher)?

```
566M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/
513M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/wal
257M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/wal/000005
256M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/wal/000004
56K     /persistentVolumes/prometheus/wal/000003
23M     /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0BPPPPY8B6PFAST84P26RQ
19M     /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0BPPPPY8B6PFAST84P26RQ/chunks/000001
19M     /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0BPPPPY8B6PFAST84P26RQ/chunks
16K     /persistentVolumes/prometheus/lost+found
12M     /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0SE520QR4H028VZDM3FDN2
8.0M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0SE520QR4H028VZDM3FDN2/chunks/000001
8.0M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0SE520QR4H028VZDM3FDN2/chunks
6.5M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM109VR1DTB1XP443A59B789
6.4M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0SE43NF04G3VNXA32W0NXR
6.1M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM175K2JXJ5XR5R3WP01W53P
4.7M    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM0BPPPPY8B6PFAST84P26RQ/index
4.0K    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/lock
4.0K    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM175K2JXJ5XR5R3WP01W53P/tombstones
4.0K    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM175K2JXJ5XR5R3WP01W53P/meta.json
4.0K    /persistentVolumes/prometheus/01CM109VR1DTB1XP443A59B789/tombstones
```

**Note**: last compaction failed (full disk, its really small)

Comment: any response here @malejpavouk

Comment: just trying to remember. Essentially this was really an expected behavior. The compaction is executed later than we thought.